# How do I pass a value taken in package builder to MSI package?

Tags: windows, windows-installer

I have a windows package builder where I am passing the LTEXT control value from the UI. An MSI file is created by the package builder. How do I pass a value to the MSI?

I tried setting the registry key value but that doesn't seem to be working.

Answer (score 0):

MSI packages use properties to process data during the installation. You can create an MSI with a default property value, change it from the command line or GUI at install time, or programmatically by using custom actions.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/setting-public-property-values-on-the-command-line

Since you didn't specify what package builder you are using and when exactly do you want to set the property I can't help you more at this time.